# Microsoft Exchange Server host address from computer name

Tags: java, email, outlook, exchange-server

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft Exchange Server using javax.mail.Store.
In order to do so I need an Microsoft Exchange host. When I check options in my outlook I see computer name rather than a host name.

Is there a way to get a host address having a computer name only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link that explains to get the server ip address

http://www.ehow.com/how_5959883_ip-address-exchange-server.html